# Suitable Index for improving Top N recent queries with tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am designing the schema of a database in PostgreSQL which would contain posts like Stack Overflow with tags. Users would search recent posts by different tags. From my research, I found that searching by tags would benefit from having generalized inverted index on tags column. These are the relevant columns of the table:

```
+--------+---------------------------+----------+
|  p_id  |   time                    | tags     |
+--------+---------------------------+------- --+
|    001 | 2020-04-30T23:35:50+00:00 | [CA,CD]  |                                          
|    109 | 2020-03-30T23:34:50+00:00 | [AB]     |   
|    321 | 2019-10-30T23:34:50+00:00 | [CD,AB]  |                                
+--------+---------------------------+----------+
```

However,  to show 50 most recent posts, the database would need to scan all rows which match the given tags. This could be problematic because in real world scenarios only a few tags end up becoming popular and a large portion of documents usually contain a select few tags, So majority of users would end up querying most of the data and therefore rendering the GIN on tags ineffective. I also think indexing time would not be useful because the rows selected by GIN on tags would return an unsorted list on time.

Is there a way to construct an index which could take advantage of both time as well tags or is it a trade off which cannot be improved upon?

#### Edit:

I am not benchmarking it because I am doing this exercise to learn sql. However this is the intended query I would like to run.

```
   Select p_id 
   From Table
   Where tags @> ?
    And
   time between ? and ?
```

Comment: And why don't you normalize the schema and put a junction table between posts and tags? Then the foreign key pointing to the tags can be indexed in there (with "old fashioned" B tree indexes) to support finding posts related to a tag. Then also add another compound (b tree) index on the post table indexing the timestamp and the post's id. That should work pretty well.

Comment: @stickybit How would this approach work for finding posts with multiple tags?

Comment: Please show us the query that you are running.

Comment: @GMB I have edited the question to include the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarking is not about learning SQL, it is about learning about performance.  And your proposed query doesn't match you description, as "50 most recent" should have an ORDER BY...DESC and a LIMIT 50, rather than having a BETWEEN conditions on time in the WHERE clause.

If you have a GIN index on tags and a regular index on time, then it will have two choices.  If your tags are very selective, it pulls out all of the tagged entries with the GIN index, and then sorts the small number of rows.  Sorting a small number of rows is fast.  If the tags are very popular, it will walk the time index and stop once it catches its LIMIT.  It should make reasonably intelligent decisions about which of those will be faster if it has reasonable statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose where format for effective pagination but yeah it cannot be used for finding first N results. Anyway, this answers my question about indexes which was the problem, so I have accepted it.